# HP DL580 G7 "Temp 20" high, fans at 90%

Tags: hpe

We've recently purchased as used HP DL580 G7, and we noticed within a few hours of hookup that the fans were ramping up very high. I then proceeded to configure the iLO 3 to see what was causing the fan ramp, but the only temp sensor which reads high (within 10 degrees C of 'Caution'- item is ~50C, Caution @ 60C) is "Temp 20". There's nothing in any of the documentations I've found on Google, or forums anywhere which will tell me where this sensor is.

I have tried updating the firmware on the iLO 3 to the latest (1.90), however it only seems to quiet the fans down for a few hours. 
All of the other temps are well within norms, with a very large headroom before approaching their 'Caution' temp.

Would anyone happen to now which part/location on the server is "Temp 20"?
Thanks!
The fans will only ramp up when "Temp 20" is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ways to get more information:

1. Use putty to SSH to iLO then `show system1/sensor1` to display specific sensors.
2. Use LoCfg to issue an XML `GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH` command.
3. Update your BIOS, since that hold the sensor name text.
4. Use `ipmitool` to pull the IPMI fields for the sensor.

In the commands above pay attention to all fields since there is information about the type/zone of the sensor.  For example location information of "PCI 5" would pretty much tell you where the sensor is.

References:

- [iLO Scripting Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20181208192559/http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02237707.pdf)
- [LoCfg](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_8ecea286efa34adfb79bcbb697) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20181208193722/https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_8ecea286efa34adfb79bcbb697))
- [ipmitool](https://github.com/ipmitool/ipmitool)